# what is difference between "to" and "from" in the following sentences?

Tags: prepositions

What is difference between following two sentences.

> It is 200 miles **to** New York.
> It is 200 miles **from** New York.

Answer (score 2):

A simple statement of the distance between two points could take the form
*It is 200 miles from A to B.*
where A is the starting point for the measurement and B is the ending point.
(Of course, you could reverse A and B in that statement.)

Sometimes you don't need to mention both start and end points. For example, in your first sentence, you could assume that the start point is "here", where the speaker is located.

*It is 200 miles [from here] to New York.*

In the second sentence, the end point is missing. It may have been mentioned in the context, though, for example:

If we are in New York,
*How far away is Washington D.C.?

It is 200 miles from New York.*

So, the normal way of stating a distance is "from" a start point "to" an end point. When one of the two words and its point is missing, the context must supply that information.